# Confusion in max connections allowed in AWS RDS types

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I know we can find the max connections by `{DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}`(12582880 is the magic number for my AWS resources). However, for **db.m4.large** (8 GB RAM) I checked online at many places that the maxConnections are 648. However, when I made the calculations, I found

8 * 1000000000/12582880 = 635.7844944877

8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 12582880 = 682.6684027822

Similarly for **db.t2.small**

2 * 1000000000/12582880 = 158.9461236219

2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 12582880  = 170.6671006955

acc to the internet: 150

Please help with finding the correct number. I cannot open MySQL console on the AWS instance due to some restrictions.

Comment: This might help you ?  https://serverfault.com/questions/862387/aws-rds-connection-limits

Answer (score 3):

This AWS page has a table of containers and max_connections limits (default):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.Performance.html

excerpt:

> db.t2.small 45
>
> db.t2.medium 90
>
> db.t3.small 45
>
> db.t3.medium 90
>
> db.r3.large 1000

Text says:

> the default connection limit is derived using a formula based on the DBInstanceClassMemory value.